# Can't get php POST sent by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I know there's a lot of similar questions here, but I looked up over 20 of them, and no solutions worked for me.

Here's the problem: I'm sendind an ajax post value to my index.php. When I look at Firebug, the value is there, but when I try to echo it on the page, the POST is empty. I'm really stucked on this.

Here's my full code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
        echo $_POST['action'];
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- JQUERY LIBRARY AND SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php">Test</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('a').on('click', function()
            {                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {action: 'clicked'},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('Done!');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using AJAX to send a a variable to a page which is already rendered on your browser. This will never work because the PHP your're getting the variable from has been run server-side and returned via AJAX, not in the page you're currently viewing.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not try to print that to the page, but simply prepends the whole HTML document with a "clicked" string, in the ajax response. If you want to show this in the browser, you need print that *data* to the page. If you inspect the console in FireBug, you will see that the response for the Ajax call is exactly what I described above.

Now if you want to print that value back to your page, here is my suggestion, you create a separate file, **ajax.php**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    echo $_POST['action'];
}
?>
```

And fix your index.php to include some element where you are going to print that value to. I.e. add `<div id="response-results"></div>` just after your  element. Then change your Ajax call to go to *ajax.php*, not index.php.

Now you need to populate that Ajax response to the rendered page, and this can be done simply with jQuery like:

```
$("#response-results").html(data);
```

Ofcourse, this goes into the **success** handler of the ajax call.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to print the value on the page. I simply need this value on the POST to do another logics with it. Understand?

Comment: Did you inspect the response of your Ajax call in Firebug? Or in the console? What does get printed there? It seems to me that you are confronted with a totally different issue here.

Answer (score 0):

As `Jay Blanchard` said
You're using AJAX to send a a variable to a page which is already rendered on your browser. This will never work because the PHP your're getting the variable from has been run server-side and returned via AJAX, not in the page you're currently viewing.
**Try this it will work :**

**index.php :**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
        echo $_POST['action'];
    }
?>
```

**main.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- JQUERY LIBRARY AND SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#123">Test</a>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('a').on('click', function()
            {                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {action: 'clicked'},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        // console.log(data);
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [R J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4116300/r-j) commented, it's impossible to do what I was trying to.

That happens because once my page is loaded, the top PHP script is proccessed, but there's nothing on my POST.

After my call to Ajax, the page is rendered again but the top PHP script will get nothing cause it's **SERVER SIDE**. Turns out that I even could print out my Ajax data on the page, but the PHP $_POST would never get its value.

Thank you guys.